# What can I do to be invisible for the IR-camera on board of a police helicopter?

Tags: thermodynamics, thermal-radiation, thermal-conductivity

I think we all have seen the images of crime suspects, running in the dark of the night to escape the police, made with the help of infrared cameras. What can I do to be invisible to these cameras when I run from a bank I just robbed, through gardens, jumping over fences, but not running through long tunnels, or through woods with densely packed trees? When I run without having done anything (except robbing the bank) I show up on the screens connected to these cameras as a highlighted "blob" looking remotely human.

Should I wear a suit filled with ice, enclosing my entire body? Or would that also be visible, because in that case, I can imagine you see a dark human blob on the screen because the temperature of that suit is lower than my surroundings (unless it's a cold winter night, but let's assume it's a normal summer night or winter night if I lived on the southern hemisphere).

Should I wear a suit with excellent heat-isolation enclosing my body and which I've prepared in such a way that it has the same temperature as the air that night?

Keeping something (a big heat-isolating plate) above my head seems unpractical to me, and some parts of my body will certainly show up on the screen helicopter with the cops in it.

What else can I do to be invisible while still being able to run freely?

By the way, I'm not planning anything...

Comment: Not robbing a bank is also a solution :) Maybe cover yourself with aluminum (or some other metal that will reflect light, aluminum foil just happens to be available in the supermarket)? It will reflect IR back to your body and prevent it from reaching the camera.

Comment: Carry an umbrella.

Comment: Be dead, but not long enough ago that decay processes have taken hold seriously.

Comment: http://www.askaprepper.com/how-to-hide-from-thermal-vision/.

Comment: Freeze yourself to 42 degrees below zero.  You should be below the detection threshold.

Comment: @eranreches or, only rob the bank when the big thermometer on the front says 98.6.

Comment: @Countto10-That's a good article indeed!

Comment: Pretty related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/142971/25301

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Military gear is typically pretty good at trumping police gear.  BAE systems recently came out with an [adaptive camouflage system](https://www.popsci.com/technology/article/2011-09/video-specially-outfitted-tank-becomes-invisible-night-infrared-sensors) that can make a tank's IR signature look like anything they please

[image: Adaptive camouflage]

The next best approach is probably confusion.  There's a long history of using Craigslist to put a "want ad" for people dressed exactly like you, then you rob a bank and the police don't know who to go after.

Failing that, an IR camera picks up heat, so anything highly insulative will be effective.  My recommendation is something fuzzy, or made of foam.  The fuzzy things tend to stay very close to room temperature

[image: Chicken Suit]

What could possibly go wrong.

Comment: Man, you're fantastic! When the shops open tomorrow, I'll directly buy that chicken suit!:-)

Comment: I'm a rich guy now! Nothing indeed went wrong!

Comment: This answer is incorrect. A thermal camera measures emitted infrared radiation, or radiance. The radiance of an object is the physical temperature times emissivity. If we assume there is no spectral dependence, emissivity varies from near 1 (matte black paint) to near zero (polished metal). The variable you need to match is the radiance. You cannot rely on anything being "highly insulating" to have the same radiance as the background, especially since the materials in the background change as you move.

Comment: @user71659 So you're saying I *shouldn't* rob a bank in a Chicken suit, and should instead use the military tech ;-)    Joking not withstanding, you're right.